# Appending barlegend to a combined graphics object?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, legending

I have a rather complex looking plot which is a combination of graphics objects, generated by

```
data = Import["o2ld.csv"];
data2 = Import["stemld.csv"];

a1 = ListContourPlot[data, Contours -> 25, Axes -> False, 
PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> False, 
ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", PlotRange -> {0.001, 100}];

a2 = ListPlot3D[data2, ClippingStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotRange -> {0.001, 1}, 
PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.33]];

level = -0.01; gr = 
Graphics3D[{Texture[a1], EdgeForm[], 
 Polygon[{{0, 0, level}, {200, 0, level}, {200, 200, level}, 
{0, 200, level}}, 
 VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 
 1}}]}, Lighting -> "Neutral"];

 out = Show[a2, gr, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 BoxStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Black, Thin], 
 ViewPoint -> {-0.35, -2, 1.5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "Proportion"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], 
 Ticks -> {{{0, 0}, {40, 0.5}, {80, 1}, {120, 1.5}, {160, 2}, 
 {200,  2.5}}, {{0, 0}, {40, 0.5}, {80, 1}, {120, 1.5}, {160, 
 2}, {200,  2.5}}, {0, 0.5, 1}}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Which produces graphics like; 
[image]

What I would like to do is add a bar legend to the right of the right, based on the values from data (a1). I can create the precise bar easily enough with

```
 vr = BarLegend[{"DarkRainbow", {0, Max[data]}}, 25];
```

But as this is not a graphics object, I cannot get it to display in with Show. Nor can I seem to get it working with epilog or inset. Does anyone have any idea how to include the bar to the right? I can included csv files for ease of recreation if required, downloadable in a RAR [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=89424804368267636644&t=8942480436826763664489404).

Comment: What about using `GraphicsRow`?

Comment: Have you seen `Legended[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those "I'm not even sure how to ask this" kind of questions. You could be asking any (or all) of the following questions.

### How do I add a legend to appear on a `ListContourPlot`?

All you need to do is add `PlotLegends->Automatic` to your `ListContourPlot`:

```
a1=ListContourPlot[data, Contours->25,Axes->False,
  PlotRangePadding->0, Frame->False,ColorFunction->"DarkRainbow", 
  PlotRange->{0.001,100}, PlotLegends->Automatic];
```

[image]

The legend will be drawn on the same 3D surface as its associated plot.

### How do I make a `BarLegend` object into a `Graphics` object?

It already is a `Graphics` object in `StandardForm`. From the docs:

> BarLegend is displayed in StandardForm as a graphics object.

### How do I place a `Graphics` object in the `Epilog` of a `Graphics3D` object?

Use `Epilog` with `Inset` to position the object.

```
vr = BarLegend[{"DarkRainbow", {0, Max[data]}}, 25];
out = Show[a2, gr, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
BoxStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Black, Thin], 
ViewPoint -> {-0.35, -2, 1.5}, 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "Proportion"}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], 
Ticks -> {{{0, 0}, {40, 0.5}, {80, 1}, {120, 1.5}, {160, 2}, 
{200,  2.5}}, {{0, 0}, {40, 0.5}, {80, 1}, {120, 1.5}, {160, 
2}, {200,  2.5}}, {0, 0.5, 1}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
Epilog -> Inset[vr, {Right, Center}, {Right, Center}]]
```

[image]

The object will sit in front of the 3D object and will not move as the 3D object is rotated.

### How do I place a `Graphics` object wherever I want in the scene of a `Graphics3D` object?

It *should* be the same as you did with the `ListContourPlot a1`, but the `ListPlot3D a2` disappears every time I try it. Must be a bug.

```
vr = BarLegend[{"DarkRainbow", {0, Max[data]}}, 25];
legendLeft = 190; legendWidth = 40; 
legendHeight = 200; legendDepth = 100;
legend3D = 
  Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], {Texture[
      Rasterize[vr, Background -> None, ImageResolution -> 200]], 
     Polygon[{{legendLeft, legendDepth, 0}, {legendLeft + legendWidth,
         legendDepth, 0}, {legendLeft + legendWidth, legendDepth, 
        legendHeight}, {legendLeft, legendDepth, legendHeight}}, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}}];

out = Show[a2, gr, legend3D, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
   BoxStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Black, Thin], 
  ViewPoint -> {-0.35, -2, 1.5}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "Proportion"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold], 
  Ticks -> {{{0, 0}, {40, 0.5}, {80, 1}, {120, 1.5}, {160, 2}, {200, 
  2.5}}, {{0, 0}, {40, 0.5}, {80, 1}, {120, 1.5}, {160, 2}, {200, 
  2.5}}, {0, 0.5, 1}}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the excellent answer by Robert Jacobson, I eventually found it's possible too to use placed with the graphics object in A2, as laid out below.

```
data = Import["o2ld.csv"];
data2 = Import["stemld.csv"];

a1 = ListContourPlot[data, Contours -> 25, Axes -> False, 
PlotRangePadding -> 0, Frame -> False, 
ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", PlotRange -> {0.001, 100}];

 a2 = Legended[
 ListPlot3D[data2, ClippingStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotRange -> {0.001, 1}, 
PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.33], ImageSize -> 500], 
 Placed[BarLegend[{"DarkRainbow", {0, Max[data]}}, 25, 
 LegendLayout -> "Row", LegendMarkerSize -> 500, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 16}], Below]];

level = -0.01; gr = 
Graphics3D[{Texture[a1], EdgeForm[], 
Polygon[{{0, 0, level}, {200, 0, level}, {200, 200, level}, {0, 
  200, level}}, 
VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
Lighting -> "Neutral"];

vr = BarLegend[{"DarkRainbow", {0, Max[data]}}, 25];

out = Show[a2, gr, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 BoxStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Black, Thin], 
 ViewPoint -> {-0.35, -2, 1.5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {" mm", "  mm", "Ratio"}, 
 LabelStyle -> {Directive[Black], FontSize -> 15}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style["(a) (i) Spatial map of stem divisions", FontSize -> 20], 
  Ticks -> {{{0, 0}, {40, 0.5}, {80, 1}, {120, 1.5}, {160, 2}, {200, 
   2.5}}, {{0, 0}, {40, 0.5}, {80, 1}, {120, 1.5}, {160, 2}, {200,
    2.5}}, {0, 0.5, 1}}, ImageSize -> 700];
```

This yields the image below (with minor stylistic differences to original, just for clarity, but idea should be there). So this is another option anyway!

[image]